# Replace state value in redux reducer conditionally

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux

I want to create a new object literal in ES6 in my redux reducer that overrides a key only if the action contains a specific property.

`return { ...state, items: newItems, lastRefresh: action.meta && action.meta.timestamp }`

This code would set `lastRefresh` to `undefined` if `action.meta` or `action.meta.timestamp` is not defined.

I know the long form would be something like:

```
let result = {
  ...state,
 items: newItems
}

if (action.meta && action.meta.timestamp) {
  result.lastRefresh = action.meta.timestamp
}

return result
```

But it seems to be to verbose. Is something like that possible with `Object.assign` maybe?

Comment: I'd say that example looks perfectly fine.  It works, and it's readable.  Besides, optimizing for readability generally beats optimizing for fewer keystrokes :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you really want is to override state.lastRefresh:

```
return { 
  ...state, 
  items: newItems, 
  lastRefresh: action.meta && action.meta.timestamp ? action.meta.timestamp : state.lastRefresh
}
```

Comment: I accept that as an answer but will go with the more readable approach outlined in my OP by what @markerikson commented there.

Comment: I don't see why the one you wrote at OP would be more readable. Ternary operators are made for that, to assign values into a variable which in this case is an object property, you just need to get used to it.

And you get a plus in performance.